# Почему вопрос не был переоткрыт, хотя был конкретизирован?

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия, переоткрытие-вопросов

Наткнулся на один [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1514880/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8).

Когда я его в первый раз увидел, он имел рейтинг `-1` и был закрыт по причине "Необходимо конкретизировать". Редко я вижу вопросы почти не заминусованые, но закрытые. Решил вчитаться в вопрос.

На самом деле проблема вопроса была вот в чём:

- В вопросе был приведён текст довольно большой задачи (оформлен так себе);
- Код (тоже немаленький, ещё и с кривыми отступами);
- Объяснение проблемы было, но так как всё было "в одной куче", то это объяснение трудно было заметить;

Я решил спасти вопрос. Предложил [правку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/850445) (её приняли) и добавил на проверку на переоткрытие. ИМХО, правка очень сильно улучшила читаемость вопроса. Но почему-то вопрос [не был переоткрыт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/850529).

Возможно из вопроса действительно стоит убрать часть задания (так как с частью задания проблемы не было, код работал), но вопрос был ***конкретизирован***, собственно проблема чётко обозначена.

Может, стоит переоткрыть?

Comment: Переоткрыл вопрос.

Comment: Может я чего то не правильно понял, но тяжело дать объективный ответ. Нет примера входных данных, это раз. Какая логика применима для определения скачка, это два. То есть, есть понимание, что курс сильно вырос или сильно упал. Что значит "сильно"? В каких значениях, в абсолютных? в относительных? Действительно, очень объемный вопрос и много времени уходит разбираться, что мало принесет пользы для сообщества в целом (мнение)

Comment: @Dmitry конечно, автор вопроса не позаботился о том, чтобы получить ответ. Вопрос был оформлен плохо и закрыт соверешнно логично. Но я не считаю, что если кто-то решил дать ответ на этот вопрос, то стоит ему мешать, пусть отвечает.

Comment: @aepot я не спорю, я дал пояснения, почему я не поддержал переоткрытие. Мой голос там присутствует, считаю хорошим тоном

Comment: Btw, по первой ссылке 404, сложно понять о чём речь.

Comment: @DiMithras, за час до вашего комментария автор удалил свой вопрос (да, "как ни мучалась, а все же умерла...")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос был закрыт видимо потому, что проблема была не очень подробно описана (как и писал `@Dmitry` в комментарии). Но автор удалил вопрос и задал [новый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1515527/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8), потому что для того, чтобы конкретизировать вопрос, его надо было полностью переписать. Новый вопрос хорошо оформлен, понятен и уже получил 2 голоса "за".

В общем, всё замечательно.